# Android AWS Upload not starting

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to upload videos stored in the phone to S3. 
After reading the documentation, here is what I wrote:

```
public void fileUpload(View view, File path){
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "us-east-1:b5a64400-xxxxxxx", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
        );

        s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
        s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1));

        TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());
        TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(
                "video",     /* The bucket to upload to */
                "file.mov",       /* The key for the uploaded object */
                  path       /* The file where the data to upload exists */
        );


    }
```

I don't have any error, but nothing is uploaded to the bucket. 
The only warning I see is:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider: No valid credentials found in SharedPreferences
```

But a post on SO says that is is normal.

Here is how I get the file:

```
 String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20161023_110808.mp4";
 File fileObjectFromPath = new File(filePath);
```

Did I miss something ? 
Any input will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i think [this](http://valuestack.io/index.php/2016/10/27/upload-images-to-the-aws-from-android/)  will help you, it has all the required things about the aws